# Getting a corrupted XLS file using NPOI

Tags: c#, xls, npoi

I tried to debug this code, but I didn't manage.  Do any of you have any idea why my script creates a corrupted XLS file?

```
string strCaleSalvareTest = @"C:\Users\andrei.tudor\Documents\TipMacheta.xls";
HSSFWorkbook wbXLS;
strEr = "Er";
try
{
    fsXLSCitire = new FileStream(strCaleSalvareTest, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    wbXLS = new HSSFWorkbook(fsXLSCitire);

    strEr = string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    strEr = ex.Message;
}
```

When I try to run this, it jumps from wbXLS creation to the catch exception block.

Comment: What is the exception? You should always include relevant information like that in your question.

Comment: this isn't really the place to be saying why doesn't my code work, take a look at the documentation here https://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation and how to ask a question that's not off topic and wont get your questions voted to be closed http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: there is no exception , the excel is created but is corupted and is also empty

Comment: Your question says at the end that 'it jump from wbXLS creation to the catch exception'...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception because you are creating a new `FileStream` for writing (`FileAccess.Write`) and passing it to the constructor of `HSSFWorkbook` which is expecting to be able to *read* from the stream.  The file is corrupt because the `FileStream` is creating the file, but nothing is ever written to it.

If you're just trying to create a new blank workbook and save it to a file, you can do that as shown below.  Note that you need to add at least one worksheet to the new workbook, or you will still generate a corrupt file.

```
// Create a new workbook with an empty sheet
HSSFWorkbook wbXLS = new HSSFWorkbook();
ISheet sheet = wbXLS.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

// Write the workbook to a file
string fileName = @"C:\Users\andrei.tudor\Documents\TipMacheta.xls";
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    wbXLS.Write(stream);
}
```

If you're trying to read an existing workbook OR create a new one if it doesn't exist, you need to do something like this:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\andrei.tudor\Documents\TipMacheta.xls";
HSSFWorkbook wbXLS;

try
{
    // Try to open and read existing workbook
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        wbXLS = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // Create a new workbook with an empty sheet
    wbXLS = new HSSFWorkbook();
    wbXLS.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
}

ISheet sheet = wbXLS.GetSheetAt(0);  // Get first sheet

// ... 

// Write workbook to file
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    wbXLS.Write(stream);
}
```